# Dead Loop and cant read all keyword when reading file using fstream::getline()

Tags: c++, fstream

Question Description：  I read a file using fstream, when I  extract data using istream::operator>>.I found dead loop, getline() seems to do not work.what's more,the code cant find all the keyword. I can’t find causes of the problem.
inputfile：

- @contact           0           0
- glob_id       nbr_id                force                   b
- 1001009     2001309  1.936503748e-013  5.980546471e+000
- 1001011     2001311  7.548735960e-018  9.524005670e-001
- 1001014     2001314  6.246652435e-029  9.048956149e-001
- @cross_flat           0           0
- glob_id      nbr_id                 force                   b
- 1001009     2001309  1.936503748e-013  5.980546471e+000
- 1001011     2001311  7.548735960e-018  9.524005670e-001
- @contact           0           2
- glob_id      nbr_id                 force                   b
- 1001009     2001309  1.936503748e-013  5.980546471e+000
- @cross_flat           0           0
- glob_id      nbr_id                 force                   b
- 1001009     2001309  1.936503748e-013  5.980546471e+000
- 1001011     2001311  7.548735960e-018  9.524005670e-001

code:

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <cstdlib>
     #include<cstdio>
     #include<fstream>
     #include <map>
     #include <string>
     using namespace std;
        int main()
        {
        fstream file;
        char fileName[128];
        char keyWord[128]={"@contact"};
        char tempWord[256];

        //sprintf()
        int step=0,substep=0;
        unsigned long globelId=0;
        unsigned long nbr_id=0;
        double bForce;
        double Force;
        bool bNextLineEmty=false;
        file.open("demo.text",fstream::in);
        if(!file.is_open())
        {
            cout<<"Error Opeing File！" <<endl;

        }

        while (!file.eof())
        {
            file.getline(tempWord,256);
            char  dumpChar[256];
            int pos=0;
            if(strncmp(keyWord,tempWord,7)==0)
            {

// judge  next line is blank or not  
                while(!bNextLineEmty)
                {

                    file.getline(dumpChar,256);
                    pos=file.tellg();
                    file.getline(dumpChar,256);
// if next line is blank,then bNextLineEmty is Ture,
                    if (strcmp(dumpChar,"")==0)
                    {
                        bNextLineEmty=true;
                    }
                    file.seekg(pos,ios::beg);
                    pos=file.tellg();
//read data 
                    file>>globelId>>nbr_id>>Force>>bForce;          
                }
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "I found dead loop" What's a dead loop?

Comment: The `bNextEmty` is not declared. Don't use C style character arrays. Use strings instead. Don't check for `.eof()` neither.

Comment: @Ron I guess `bNextEmty` should be `bNextLineEmty`

Comment: @DimChtz the dead loop occur when finding the first keyword and  the inner loop finished.